# How to get an Image in the foreground with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set a loading-GIF in the foreground of the users screen during an Ajax-request. The Gif should be in the middle of the webpage also if the user scrolls down or up. Is there a layout method in Bootstrap to realize this?

I'm not sure where to place this HTML snippet

```
<div id='loading' style='display: none'>
    <img src="fonts/loading.gif" title="Loading" class="img-responsive center-block"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with CSS. Create an overlay wich will cover the page (overlay) by setting the `z-index` to `9999` to make sure it's at the foreground. To actually set the spinner in the center of the screen you can use `top` and `translate` properties. For example:

CSS:

```
.loading-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.loading-overlay > .inner
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The HTML markup looks like this:

```
<div class="loading-overlay"><div class="inner"><img src="fonts/loading.gif" title="Loading" class="img-responsive center-block"/></div></div>
```

To add a transculent background to the overlay, simply add `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);` to the `.loading-overlay` class.

Good luck!

Comment: Well, this worked perfectly. Thank you very much for this helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can place it anywhere but you would need to style the div using CSS to keep it in the middle of the page

This should work for you:

```
#loading{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```